# Add a top bar to a wordpress theme without editing the header.php file?

Tags: php, filters, wp-head

I would like to add a top bar to wordpress without having to edit any theme files. Are there any filters that I can use to achieve this.

I want to be able to do this in the function.php file. This way it is easy to just dump in the code in the future without having to worry about changing the code in the theme files.

If there are no filters that can do this then I will use the header.php file in a child theme to do make the changes.

Comment: depends on your theme. at least the latest default themes 'Twenty...' now have `wp_body_open();` just inside the body tag.

Comment: You could also do it via plugin and place it somewhere in the footer, but then displace the rest of the content with positioning... ..this could get tricky with some themes though.

Comment: it would be nice if you mention the theme you use so that we can help you with code

Comment: @Michael, that allows you to edit at the beginning of the body tag. This may be desirable but doesn't explicitly allow one to edit the beginning of the header navigation which is a more foolproof solution. It appears there is no filter for what I am asking about.

Comment: @TonyDjukic, sorry should have said that I am looking for a solution without having to install additional plugins.

Comment: @RaashidDin, I would like a theme independent solution. Hence I am looking to add this to the function.php file and not overriding the header.php file.

Comment: Courtney, I wasn’t talking about a downloaded plugin but rather one that you code and add yourself that serves a single purpose.  You’re saying you want it theme independent, so that’s the only way.  If you add it to function.php, then it’s part of your theme/child theme and therefor not “theme independent”.

Comment: re: 'beginning of the header navigation' - do you mean inside the header navigation, at the beginning of it? there are various hooks related to wp_nav_menu... or before the header navigation? please describe more detailed what your 'top bar' would look like and where exactly you want to add it.

Comment: @TonyDjukic, sorry I misunderstood what you were trying to say. I am just looking to add it to the function.php file so in a sense, yes it is a plugin. However I am asking about the mechanism to make that possible. Like the name of a hook or something like that.

Comment: @Michael, Have a look at the pen below. The section is pink is what I am trying to add.

https://codepen.io/ckhackshaw/pen/vYNMOoy

Comment: my suggestion stays the same; if there is nothing above your newly added section, and if your theme supports 'wp_body_open()', I still think this is a good option. what theme are you planning to use, and have you contacted the theme's developer for support?